# Python 2.4 OAuth compatibilty

Tags: python, django, oauth

I have installed python oauth on my python2.4 platform, however making the python twitter package work requires some tweaks in oauth.. I am quite new to python but I assume I cannot alter the egg.. how do I install a non-egg version and how do I remove the egg safely ?

Answer (score 0):

Python eggs (like java jar files) use the zip format. So to answer your question on how to make your tweaks:

1. Find the file location
2. Navigate to location, make a backup copy
3. If the file is stored as oauth.egg, unzip it
4. Start modifying!

### Find the egg location

Open up a python interpreter and run the following:

```
>>> import oauth
>>> oauth.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth/__init__.pyc'
```

Your path will differ, but that will tell you where to look. Often the source code will be unpacked and available in the same directory as a .py file, in this case *oauth.py*.

(By the way the `__file__` attribute is available on all modules unless they represent linked C libraries, but that should not be your case with oauth.)

I'll skip the file navigation, backup, and unzip details, as those will depend on your system.

### Removing a Python Egg Safely

I'm afraid my knowledge is lacking here. Removing the egg file is easy, but I'm not at all sure how to check for dependencies from other packages, other than running `$ ack python.module.to.remove` across your python library. But some basic facts that may help

1. Directories that include `__init__.py` in them are treated as part of the python path. See [Modules and Packages](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/tut/node8.html#SECTION008400000000000000000)
2. Python eggs will add a [.pth file](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/inst/search-path.html) containing additional places to add to the path.
3. `>>> import sys; sys.path` will show every directory that Python searches for modules/packages.
4. The PYTHONPATH environment variable can be configured to add paths you choose to the python search path

*PS* If you are new to Python, I highly recommend finding out more about IPython. It makes the Python intepreter much nicer to deal with.

Good luck and welcome to Python!